# Example to call java web service (Addition of two numbers) from Android using AsyncTask

Tags: android, web-services, android-studio

I need working example to call web service of addition of two numbers passed from Android activity using AsyncTask and show the result Android EditText.

Comment: I made web service from netbeans. I followed serveral examples given on various website but it prompt error like // com.android.builder.merge.DuplicateRelativeFileException: More than one file was found with OS independent path 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
 //

Answer (score 0):

```
class DownloadFilesTask extends AsyncTask<Integer, Integer, Integer>
 {

protected Integer doInBackground(Integer... integers)
 {
     int a = 1 ;
     int b = 2 ;
     int c = a+b;
     return c;
 }

   protected void onPostExecute(Integer result) {
      yourEditText.setText(result + "");
   }
 }
```

Comment: I want to call function of addition from web service.

Comment: I mean calculation process should occur at serverSide. But you have performed it on client side